# How do I associate python with py files in bash

Tags: python, linux, bash

A common question is "how do I make *my* python script executable without explicitly calling python on the command line?", and the answer is `chmod +x` it and then add `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the start of the script.

That is *not* the question I'm asking.

What I would like to do is tell bash, or python, or whatever is responsible for file-handling to treat all .py files that have the execute bit set as if they have the shebang at the beginning whether or not they actually do.

I understand that in Windows this can be done, and apparently in Gnome for the use-case where you double-click on a .py script from the GUI. I could have sworn I remembered hearing about an equivalent way of specifying a handler from the shell.

Why I want to know how to do this (if it's actually possible):

- Not every system uses shebang and I don't want to clutter up files in a cross-platform project with it.
- If I'm submitting a patch to a project I don't own, it's slightly obnoxious for me to put stuff unrelated to the patch into it for my own convenience.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, not possible. `bash` will execute any executable file without a shebang or a magic number as a shell script. Shebang is also standard, it does not "clutter up" a file as it's only one line, and you shouldn't put it into many files, only those you expect you'll use as commands (i.e. don't put it into files you're only importing and not expecting to directly execute). If you need to execute a library file for testing, use `python libfile.py`; you can `alias p=python` for your own convenience if `python` is too long for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean [binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc)?

> binfmt_misc is a capability of the Linux kernel which allows arbitrary executable file formats to be recognized and passed to certain user space applications, such as emulators and virtual machines.

So you want to register an entry to it, so everytime you want to execute a `.py` file, the kernel will pass it to /usr/bin/python.

You can do it by trying something like this

```
# load the binfmt_misc module
if [ ! -d /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc ]; then
  /sbin/modprobe binfmt_misc
fi
if [ ! -f /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register ]; then
  mount binfmt_misc -t binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
fi

echo ':Python:E::py::/usr/bin/python:' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

If you're using Debian-based distribution, you have to install [binfmt-support](https://packages.debian.org/sid/binfmt-support).

You can add `:Python:E::py::/usr/bin/python:` to `/etc/binfmt.d/python.conf` so it's permenent after reboot.

Comment: Holy cow, that sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try it and get back on how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: "Not every system uses shebang...". And even fewer systems are going to support binfmt_misc.

Answer (score 1):

Rio6's answer is correct. Only it is supported on practically no operating systems. You will need binfmt, you can compile it yourself from source at [This git address](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/binfmt-support.git)